# Can I legally make a boggle variant?

Tags: game-design, variants, boggle

Is it legal to create a boggle version that has a different name, language and rules without being sued by hasbro?

Comment: If it has a different name, language, and rules, what makes it a Boggle variant instead of it being a completely different game?

Comment: Sorry but legal advice should be gotten from a lawyer not a board game Q&A.

Comment: This is a legal question, not one about a board game.

Comment: Bound to be legal to make — but do you want to sell it?

Comment: You can use the Boggle game mechanics, but have to avoid any Intellectual Property that falls under trademark or copyright, because Hasbro will definitely go after you if you do, and possibly even if you don't. If you change the rules, I think you can avoid this potential liability entirely.  I highly recommend researching [Words with Friends vs. Scrabble](https://www.quora.com/Did-Scrabble-sue-Words-with-Friends-What-happened)

Answer (score 2):

Copyright only covers specific implementations, i.e. the exact wording of the rules.  Patents are a nonissue in this case, Boggle was released in 1972 so any patent applying to it would have expired years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Copyright, trademarks, and patents are complicated subjects and if you are really concerned about this sort of thing you should consult an Intellectual Property attorney.  Or if you don't want to spend money on this problem I hope you're covered by fair use.

Comment: Copyright is unlikely to arise in this situation; patents possibly, passing off almost certainly.  But +1 for 'consult an attorney': you get what you pay for in legal advice, and SE is free.

Comment: You forgot about trademarks.  Answer updated to include more things you should consult a lawyer for.